# Python subprocess library fails when launch in systemd service

Tags: python, subprocess, systemd

I am using the function `subprocess.run` and `subprocess.check_output` that works great when I launch my python code. I then create a service in systemd but the process crashes when getting to these functions

From the log journalctl:

```
Nov 30 19:19:24 srv2 python3[3369]:
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
Nov 30 19:19:24 srv2 python3[3369]:
     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
Nov 30 19:19:24 srv2 python3[3369]:
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
Nov 30 19:19:24 srv2 python3[3369]:
     restore_signals, start_new_session)
Nov 30 19:19:24 srv2 python3[3369]:
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
Nov 30 19:19:24 srv2 python3[3369]:
     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
Nov 30 19:19:24 srv2 python3[3369]:
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mosquitto_passwd': 'mosquitto_passwd'
```

Comment: Do you know what is ```mosquitto_passwd```?

Comment: mosquitto_passwd is the task i launch. I was also using subprocess.check_output(['pidof',<process name>]), working when launching in python but no longer when launched from a service

Answer (score -1):

For some reason the service goes thru this morning, I added `Type=simple` and set user to root but not sure if it was the cause

```
[Unit]
Description=my service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/home/python/service
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/python/service/main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```